# Cast a string to a date in SQL Server with this format MM-YYYY

Tags: sql-server, date, casting

I have a string with this format `Oct-2014`, `May-2014` and I want to convert it to a date of any format like `01-10-2015`.

Do you know how I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `CONVERT` with style 106 to `CONVERT` the character to `DATETIME` and then use style 105 for format `dd-mm-yyyy`. Something like this.

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(20) = 'Oct-2014'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CONVERT(DATE,REPLACE('01 ' + @var,'-',' '),106),105)
```